# show and hide php update and delete messages?

Tags: php, html, css

how can i show update message and delete message only if i pressed the submit button because every time when i open the page or reload it you can see the message bar without me pressing the submit button

```
<?php require_once("header.php");  ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="RTL" lang="Ar">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>


<link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body> 



<?php

if(isset($_GET['language_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['language_id']) && $_GET['language_id'] > 0 ){

$language_id = $_GET['language_id'];

}

?>
<?php include ("connection.php"); ?>
<?php
   $msg = "";
   if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
       if(is_numeric($_POST['language_id'])){

          $language_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,htmlspecialchars($_POST['language_id']));
          $language_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,htmlspecialchars($_POST['language_name']));



            if ($language_name == "")
            {
                $msg = "يرجى تعبيئة كافة الحقول" ;
            }
            else 
            {                   
                $sql = mysqli_query ($link,"UPDATE `programming_language` SET `language_name`='".$language_name."' 
                    WHERE `language_id`='".$language_id."' "); 
                    if($sql){

                         $msg = "تمت عملية التعديل بنجاح";
                        // header ("location:edit_programming_language.php");   
                    }                 


            }

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error !";
        }

    }
    else
    {   
        if(isset($_GET['language_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['language_id']) && $_GET['language_id'] > 0 ){

                 $language_id = $_GET['language_id'];

            $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `programming_language` WHERE `language_id` ='".$language_id."' ")  or die(mysqli_error($link));  
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query) ){
              $language_id = $row ['language_id'];
              $language_name = $row['language_name'];


            }
        }   

    }
?>

<div class="page-container">
 <div  class="alert  alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close" >
                &times;
            </button>
 <p><?php    echo $msg;        ?></p>
 </div> 
<div class="edit-programming-language">

<form method= "POST" action = "" > 





                        <input type="hidden" name = "language_id" value="<?php echo $language_id ;?>" />

  <p>                     

                        <label>اسم اللغة</label>
                        <td><input type="text" name = "language_name" value="<?php echo $language_name ;?>" /></td>
       </p>
  <p>      

                        <td><input type="submit" name = "update" class="button  edit-programming-language-btn" value="تحديث البيانات"  /></td>

  </p>   

                        <input type="hidden" name = "examinee_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['language_id']; ?>" />


              </form>








</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my css code for alerts

```
.alert {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    height:25px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
}
.alert-success {
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    border-top-color: #c9e2b3;
}
.alert-danger {
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
    border-top-color: #e4b9c0;
}
.alert  p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:25px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I would just like to take a moment to mention that you should REALLY be using prepared statements rather than using mysqli_real_escape_string. Prepared statements are more secure and often faster than just running mysqli_query.

Comment: It'd be better if you share a live link or make a JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the data is posted and then print the msg.

Here is the code

```
<?php
  if($_POST){

       <div  class="alert  alert-success">
          <button type="button" class="close" >
                 &times;
          </button>
        <p><?php    echo $msg;        ?></p>
       </div>
    }    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="alert alert-success <?=isset($_POST['update']) ? '' : 'hidden' ?>">
    <button type="button" class="close" >
                &times;
    </button>
 <p><?php    echo $msg;        ?></p>
 </div>
```

This will apply the `hidden` css class to your alert box if there has been no post call. This looks like bootstrap, so the class should already be defined.

The snippet is untested, but it should give you a general idea.